Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders
I'm working on a React application using Redux and I’ve encountered a warning related to the useSelector hook. I am trying to extract data and loading state from multiple slices of the Redux store, as these two values are common across different API responses.
Error: Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders. Selectors that return the entire state are almost certainly a mistake, as they will cause a rerender whenever anything in state changes.
const {
  measureData: { data: measureViewData, loading: measureViewLoading },
  lists: { data: listData, loading: listLoading },
} = useSelector((state) => ({
  measureViewData: state.measureViewData,
  list: state.list,
}));

// Redux Store setup (reducers for both slices)
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    measureViewData: measureViewDataReducer,
    list: listReducer,
  },
});

In my app, I’m fetching data from APIs, and each slice of the state contains both data and loading properties (indicating whether the API call is in progress). I’m using useSelector to extract these properties, but I am receiving the following warning in the console, which says my selector is returning the entire root state:
Warning: Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders.
I want to be able to uniformly extract both the data and loading state from each slice, and avoid unnecessary rerenders. For example, the measureViewData slice has:
const initialState = {
data: [],
loading: false
}

And similarly, the list slice has:
const initialState = {
data: [],
loading: false
}

What I’ve Tried:

I’ve reviewed the selector, and it looks like it should only return the measureViewData and list slices, but the warning suggests that it might be returning the entire root state.
I’ve attempted restructuring the selector to explicitly extract only data and loading from each slice, but I’m still encountering the warning.
I’ve confirmed that my reducers for measureViewData and list are set up properly and both contain data and loading states.

Question:
How can I refactor my useSelector hook to extract data and loading from each slice (like measureViewData, list, etc.) and avoid the warning about returning the entire state? I want to make sure I am efficiently accessing just the data and loading state for each slice of the Redux store, and prevent unnecessary rerenders.
Is there a better pattern or approach for accessing this common structure across different API slices?

This code should not be able to cause that exact error - are you 100% sure that this error could not be caused by another useSelector usage somewhere else?

I am using useSelector like this:
const {   recentProducts: {     data: demoRecentItems,     count: demoRecentCount,     isLoading: demoRecentLoading,   },   marketplace: { data: demoStoreItems, isLoading: demoStoreLoading },   manufacturers: { data: demoManufacturerItems, isLoading: demoManufacturerLoading }, } = useSelector((state) => ({   recentProducts: state.recentProducts,   marketplace: state.marketplace,   manufacturers: state.manufacturers, })); 

That wouldn't cause that error message. Only if you had something literally with useSelector(state => state) it would cause that error message. Are you sure you don't have state => state or x => x or something along those lines in your app somewhere?

I managed to resolve the previous warning, but now I'm encountering a new warning:
"selector unknown returned a different result when called with the same parameters."
My selector looks like this:
const storeData = useSelector((state) => ({   cartItems: state.cartItems,   profileInfo: state.profileInfo,   isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn }));
Do you have any insights on what might be causing this new warning?

Issue
Your Redux state is an object with list and measureViewData properties:

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    measureViewData: measureViewDataReducer,
    list: listReducer,
  },
});


And your anonymous selector function also returns an object with the same properties:

useSelector((state) => ({
  measureViewData: state.measureViewData,
  list: state.list,
}));


I suspect that even though these values are different object references they JSON serialize equally and RTK thinks you are simply returning the root state.
It's basically the same thing as
useSelector(state => state); // { list, measureViewData }

Solution Suggestion
Compute and return the nested state properties you care about in the component.
Examples:

Single selector function that returns the deeply-nested properties:
const {
  measureData,
  measureViewIsLoading,
  listData,
  listIsLoading,
} = useSelector((state) => ({
  measureData: state.measureViewData.data,
  measureViewIsLoading: state.measureViewData.loading,
  listData: state.list.data,
  listIsLoading: state.list.loading
}));


Separate selector functions to individually return the sub-state properties to use destructuring assignment to rename the data and loading states:
const {
  data: measureData,
  loading: measureViewIsLoading,
} = useSelector(state => state.measureViewData);
const {
  data: listData,
  loading: listIsLoading,
} = useSelector(state => state.list);



